# WYSIWYG tool to inspect OpenOffice XML document features and corresponding xml element mapping

Tags: openoffice.org

Standard ECMA-376
Office Open XML File Formats
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

Is there any WYSIWYG tool available to inspect the XML corresponding to a feature in given document type?

Such tools are available for HTML/Web pages.
When I select HTML element on web page in the tool, I can see corresponding HTML code in inspect/source window.

For example, if I open a docx document in a tool and I put cursor in a word which is bold and italic (e.g. ***Hello World!***), I would like to inspect the corresponding XML for it. So the tool would have inspect window, where I would immediately see the XML version of the text in WORD file.

Comment: dear @sagaofsilence, did you manage to find something like this in the meantime?